# application started crashing when trying to login using facebook after ide error

Tags: java, android, facebook

My application was working perfectly then, after adding the following code `LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();` to disconnect from the current facebook account (a developper acount), the ide showed that an error occurred while running the app, but the application launched anyway, but when trying to login, it crashed and now it's not logging in, it keeps crashing! even though I changed nothing except adding that line of code to the next activity to make the app disconnect in case the user want to logout!

**here's my java code:**

```
public class ConnexionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button b_bb, b_back, ee, b_inscrp_formulaire, fb;
    EditText tb_pseudo, tb_mdp;
    int id;
    String name, gender, email, birthday;
    private LoginButton loginButton;
    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    Profile profile;
    //new try:

    private AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker;
    private Button customFacebookLogin;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        /*List<String> permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList("user_photos", "email",
                "user_birthday", "public_profile", "AccessToken");*/

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_connexion);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        b_inscrp_formulaire = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_inscrip_formulaire);


        fb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fb);


        loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);

        loginButton.setText("");

        loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email", "user_friends", "user_birthday"));
        //"user_photos", "email","user_birthday", "public_profile"
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                graphRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken());

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {

            }


        });


        //getting the hash key
        try {
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                    "your.package",
                    PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

        }


        //2nd way to generate hash key (or get it)
        try {
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("your.package.name", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        b_bb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_bb);
        b_back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_back);
        tb_pseudo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textbox_pseudo);
        tb_mdp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textbox_mdp);


        /////////////
        ee = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        ////////////

        b_bb.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                        b_bb.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_bb_selec);
                        break;
                    }

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {

                        b_bb.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_bb);

                        break;
                    }

                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        b_bb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                if (isAuthorized()) {

                    Intent menu_p = new Intent(ConnexionActivity.this, MenuPActivity.class);
                    menu_p.putExtra("pseudo", tb_pseudo.getText().toString());
                    startActivity(menu_p);
                } else {
                    openDialog();
                }

            }
        });


        b_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ConnexionActivity.this.finish();
            }
        });


        ee.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent menu_p = new Intent(ConnexionActivity.this, MenuPActivity.class);
                menu_p.putExtra("pseudo", "Easter");
                startActivity(menu_p);

            }
        });

        b_inscrp_formulaire.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent menu_p = new Intent(ConnexionActivity.this, InscriptionActivity.class);
                startActivity(menu_p);

            }
        });


        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                graphRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {

            }
        });


        fb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(ConnexionActivity.this, Arrays.asList("user_photos", "email",
                        "user_birthday", "public_profile"));
                profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile().getCurrentProfile();
                if (profile != null) {
                    // user has logged in
                    Intent menu_p = new Intent(ConnexionActivity.this, MenuPActivity.class);
                    menu_p.putExtra("pseudo", profile.getFirstName());
                    startActivity(menu_p);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connecté : " + profile.getFirstName() + " " + profile.getLastName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    // user has not logged in
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Non-Connecté : Erreur de connexion!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


            }
        });


        //To log out of FB:
        /*LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();*/

        //TODO: check if the user is logged in or not
       /* profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile().getCurrentProfile();
        if (profile != null) {
            // user has logged in
        } else {
            // user has not logged in
        }*/

    }

    private Boolean isAuthorized() {

        if (tb_pseudo.getText().toString().equals("Admin")
                && tb_mdp.getText().toString().equals("0000")
                ) {
            return true;
        } else
            return false;
    }

    public void openDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Mauvaise combinaison \"Pseudo\", \"Mot de passe\"");

        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

            }
        });


        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }


    public void graphRequest(AccessToken token) {
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(token, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {


                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), object.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });

        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("fields", "id,email,first_name,last_name,picture.type(large)");
        request.setParameters(b);
        request.executeAsync();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    }

}
```

Comment: post logcat error here thanks.

Comment: @BrunoFerreira it's not an error on the code or something like that, it was an ide error! now everything is running fine, but the app crashes when trying to connect.

Comment: you don't see crash log in your logcat?

Comment: @santalu yes I do, just one here it is :  'Please change caller according to com.intellij.openapi.project.IndexNotReadyException documentation: Please change caller according to com.intellij.openapi.project.IndexNotReadyException documentation'

Comment: @BrunoFerreira was the error above is what you asked me for?

Comment: yes is that error.

Comment: My application is back to connect after closing and reopening Android studio, still applying the logout line mentioned in the question  makes it crash again!!

Comment: I got the same error. But I found out that if I use Activity instead of AppcompatActivity, problem disappears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem was just in the IDE, something about indexation!! I closed and reopened the IDE and everything is working just fine.